# How to set two fieldsets side by side in html?

Tags: html, fieldset

How would I set two field sets side by side to get something like this?
 [What I am going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMOvv.png)

This is what I have so far:
[Fieldset reaches end of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQpzR.png)

Comment: Can you put your code into a codepen, codeply, or jsfiddle? You're more likely to receive help this way.

Comment: @cwanjt No. Posting your markup on those sites alone will only get a question closed as may happen to this one if it isn't fixed.

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Bootsrap's grid system.

Please check [this](https://jsbin.com/qupofal/edit?html,css,output) out for demo.

```
 <main class="container">
    <form>
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <fieldset>
            <label class="label">Firstname</label>
            <input type="text" value="Firstname" class="form-input form-control" />
          </fieldset>
           <fieldset>
            <label class="label">Lastname</label>
            <input type="text" value="Lastname" class="form-input form-control" />
          </fieldset>         
        </li>
        <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
           <fieldset>
            <label class="label">Username</label>
            <input type="text" value="Username" class="form-input form-control" />
          </fieldset>
           <fieldset>
            <label class="label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" value="Password" class="form-input form-control" />
          </fieldset>          
        </li>
      </ul>      
    </form>
  </main>
```